# Getting a discussion tab on a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, github-api

How does one add a discussion tab to their GitHub repository? For example:

[image: GitHub repository Discussions tab example]

Comment: GitHub published new information about it today https://github.blog/2020-05-06-new-from-satellite-2020-github-codespaces-github-discussions-securing-code-in-private-repositories-and-more/#discussions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the 9th of December Discussion tabs are now rolling out to all GitHub’s repos just go to settings to were you can turn off and on; issues and wikis etc, at end you will see the new discussion tab option
[view a screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj1Ew.jpg)

https://github.community/t/can-one-apply-for-github-discussions-beta/121120/550 -- Link doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for per-repository discussions like in the link you mentioned, that's a new feature that is in a limited beta at GitHub.  It will be rolling out to more repositories and projects soon and GitHub will provide more information when it's available more widely.

Comment: In repo settings the features section has an item **Get started with Discussions** with text "Engage your community by having discussions right in your repository, where your community already lives".  Clicking on the button *Setup up discussions* takes me to relative url discussions/welcome_templates and a 404 error.  Guess this feature isn't ready for prime time just yet.

Answer (score 4):

#### Update Dec 2020

You can enable it from project settings.

---

Old Answer:

As of Oct 2020, private repositories are not eligible for the Discussions beta.
Repos must:

1. Be public visibility
2. Have at least 3 contributors

---

Source: https://github.community/t/can-one-apply-for-github-discussions-beta/121120/332

Answer (score 2):

Dec - 2020

**For Private free account is does not seem possible to get the discussion tab on the actual repo**

On the free plan to add a discussion you need to first *create a team*,  then *attach a team to a repo*. Your discussions will not show in the actual repo. In order to access the discussion you need to click on the main account and then click on teams, then click on the team.

For the reason above I advise you to ditch GitHub for an interface that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment team discussions can only be created if there is a team/an organization, that seems to imply that private/personal repositories do not have a discussion. For creating a discussion with a team/in an organization you can currently refer to https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-team-discussion.

As of today 7th May 2020, GitHub, talked about team discussions in their recap of their satellite conference from yesterday, [link to recap of team discussions](https://github.blog/2020-05-06-new-from-satellite-2020-github-codespaces-github-discussions-securing-code-in-private-repositories-and-more/#discussions)